# How to assign value to Observable<objectType>?

Tags: angular

I have this code but I can't assign the data.
Why is this not working? Should I make the data an Observable?

```js
student:Observable<Student>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.service.getStudent(this.id).subscribe(data => {
    this.student = data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `student` as an `Observable` of some `BehaviorSubject`

```
_student: BehaviorSubject<Student> = new BehaviorSubject<Student>(null);
student: Observable<Student> = this._student.asObservable();
```

then to update the value of the observable `student`, we can do

```
this._student.next(newValue)  // the data of student observable is now set to newValue
```

so for your code this would look like

```
this.service.getStudent(this.id).subscribe(data => {
  this._student.next(data);
});
```

subscribing to `student` will fire with it's new value any time `this._student.next(val)` is called.